# How to implement navigation menu in batmanjs

Tags: controller, navigation, batman.js

I'm trying to build a navigation menu which current navigation item get highlighted according to the current controller action; but I can't find anything tells me how to do it!!
How can I define my navigation structure and mapped to my controllers? and how can I identify the current navigation item?
In Shopfiy I noticed they use data-section view binding, which assigns selected class to the current navigation item, how they did it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On solution that could be using [data-addclass binding](http://batmanjs.org/docs/batman.html#batman-view-bindings-data-addclass-data-removeclass) together with [equals view filter](http://batmanjs.org/docs/batman.html#batman-view-filters-equals).

Your navigation item inside data-foreach-item loop would look something like this:

```
<div
  class="navigation-item"
  data-route="routes.navigation[item]"
  data-addclass-selected="item | equals controllers.navigation.selectedItem">
</div>
```

In your controller you should have member selectedItem which gets set when ever an item gets selected.